# SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor и ThreadPoolTaskExecutor? Что лучше использовать?

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring

Написано в разных источниках что ThreadPool чаще используется  для short-live асинхронных задач.
Но у меня намного быстрее на компьютере выполняются задачи с SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor. Может я неправильно настраиваю ThreadPool? Кто работал с этим? Нужна помощь.

У меня выполняется просто серия задач - парсинг разных внешних страниц

Comment: По документации, `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` запускает новый `Thread` на каждую задачу (по-умолчанию, в неограниченном количестве), а `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` - несколько (`corePoolSize` по-умолчанию - 1). Так что вы, наверное, правы.

Comment: @zRrr, я ставил большой corePoolSize  и max но как то мне не помогало особо

Comment: размер пула потоков попробуйте поставить по количеству доступных ядер - эффект должен стать лучше. Ни очередей не будет лишних, ни простоя ядер.

Comment: @DimXenon, медленно работает так очень. SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor намного быстрее работает.

Comment: @DimXenon, судя по всему, очередей лишних как раз появится больше!

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html понятно почему, в общем. "NOTE: This implementation does not reuse threads!" Делаем быстро за счёт ресурсов. TjreadPool же ждёт когда можно будет занять один из тредов. Отсюда и разность в производительности. И в потребляемых ресурсах.